# Ubuntu 15.10 missing mouse pointer speed in settings

Tags: unity, settings, 15.10

Missing pointer settings in my settings

[image]

My xinput result:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                  id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer        id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                 id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard       id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                      id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                         id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver             id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: This seems to still be a problem in 16.04. Doesn't look exactly the same, but with a wireless mouse, it only shows the touchpad speed, which isn't the same as the mouse speed (not shown). Needed to use xset, per one of the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary fix is is to use `xset,` this seems to be ok for me:

```
xset m 02.5 1
```

This is a basic gui config setting and should be visible. I could make the `xset` command run at startup,  but it should really be fixed.

Comment: how did you make it run on startup?

Answer (score 1):

A temporary fix for me was to temporarily plug in a wired mouse. This will reveal the speed settings.

Any settings we make there will then affect all mice attached.

See [Bug #1509559](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1509559)