# On start up, need to run "xset m 0 0"

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, startup, 15.10

What is the best way to do this?

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and the mouse speed is so high it is impossible to use mouse unless I open terminal and type `xset m 0 0`

How can I make this happen when I start computer?  Also, does this take effect after logging in?

Thanks for help

Comment: Also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/691159/ubuntu-15-10-missing-mouse-pointer-speed-in-settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the `Startup Applications`.

You can get to this GUI by typing "Startup Applications" in the Ubuntu Launch button.

I'm sure the GUI is intuitive.  Just click Add.  Then give your desired command (or application) a name in the first field.  For the command field, in your case, type in:

```
xset m 0 0
```

You can also type something in the comment section to remind you the intent of this application.

After those three parameters, click Add.